# Getting a filename from react-scripts build?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, react-scripts

I am using yarn to run `react-scripts build` on a private Typescript repository. The build fails with the following message:

```
yarn build -v
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-scripts build -v
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'.
    114 |       withCredentials: true,
    115 |       headers: {
  > 116 |         Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : undefined,
        |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    117 |       },
    118 |     });
    119 |


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I understand the error, but I cannot find what file the error is in because react-scripts build doesn't seem to output the file name? I'm not sure if this is a problem with my local configuration but is there a way to get react-scripts to tell me where exactly this error is?

Comment: For what it's worth, I noticed the same after I upgraded to react-scripts 5.0.0. It used to print the file names just fine in 4.0.3.

Comment: Bug: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12647